Can My M Audio M Track 2x2 C Series Can Work Well With 250ohms Headphone?
I Want to Know That My Audio Interface M Audio 2x2 C Series Will Work With 250ohms Will it be In Moderate Loudness and Will it Change Any Frequency Response Due to Impedance Mismatch ?
My Audio Interface Headphone Output Impedance is - 10ohms
Will it sufficient to work with 250ohms headphone without any Distortion or Frequency Change ?

Why all the capitals..?

Probably a dupe for studio headphones for audio interphase?
